# nginx / passenger configuration to allows access to custom header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am using a custom header called auth_token that I'm passing to my rails backend. On localhost / webrick, I can access:

```
curl -H "auth_token: r5O_IdqpWStqmJFe0pil0Q" http://localhost:3000
```

and the header value is accessible with:

```
auth_token=request.headers["auth_token"] if request.headers["auth_token"].
```

However, when I access staging (nginx / passenger) with:

```
curl -H "auth_token: r5O_IdqpWStqmJFe0pil0Q" http://staging.domain.com/
```

It cannot access the header value. Is there any configuration I need to do to nginx / passenger to allow it to access this custom header?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix was:

underscores_in_headers on;

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#underscores_in_headers

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nginx proxy module to forward request to passenger, you need to explicitly forward this customized header:

```
proxy_set_header auth_token $http_auth_token;
```

References:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_set_header

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24http_HEADER